# How to design to reduce redundant classes in Kotlin?

Tags: java, kotlin

I'm learning the sample "Kotlin for Android Developers (the book) " at https://github.com/antoniolg/Kotlin-for-Android-Developers

There are three classes in different kt file, I think the three classes are similar, and these mulit classes  make the program complex.

How can I redesign the project framework and make project more clear?

**DbClasses.kt**

```
class DayForecast(var map: MutableMap<String, Any?>) {
    var _id: Long by map
    var date: Long by map
    var description: String by map
    var high: Int by map
    var low: Int by map
    var iconUrl: String by map
    var cityId: Long by map

    constructor(date: Long, description: String, high: Int, low: Int, iconUrl: String, cityId: Long)
            : this(HashMap()) {
        this.date = date
        this.description = description
        this.high = high
        this.low = low
        this.iconUrl = iconUrl
        this.cityId = cityId
    }
}
```

**tables.kt**

```
object DayForecastTable {
    val NAME = "DayForecast"
    val ID = "_id"
    val DATE = "date"
    val DESCRIPTION = "description"
    val HIGH = "high"
    val LOW = "low"
    val ICON_URL = "iconUrl"
    val CITY_ID = "cityId"
}
```

**DomainClasses.kt**

```
data class Forecast(
    val id: Long,
    val date: Long,
    val description: String,
    val high: Int, 
    val low: Int,
    val iconUrl: String
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of database related classes, you may think about using ORM Library that will annotate fields and generate database table schema (remove need for DayForecastTable) e.g. Room (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/index.html)

You could technically use those classes across your whole app to reduce the need for DomainClasses, although I would suggest keeping Domain layer classes to make domain model independent from database.